# probability that two randomly chosen numbers are coprime

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Is this question well posed? See here for the solution [Probability that two random numbers are coprime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64498/probability-that-two-random-numbers-are-coprime)

I have also seen it in some contests. The question asks to compute $p=\lim p_n$ where $p_n$ is the probability that two random chosen integers less than $n$ are coprime. There is no way to associate a uniform distribution to integers; so I would hesitate to call this limit a probability. So is there any rigorous way to understand this limit as a probability of some event?

See also this post

[What's the mean of all real numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439344/whats-the-mean-of-all-real-numbers)

where it is mentioned (and I agree) that the mean of reals (or integers) is undefined. But one could in the same way define a uniform distribution for reals or integers with absolute value less than $x>0$ and take the limit of the mean as $x$ goes to infinity. Then the mean of reals would be $0$.

Comment: How do you define a uniform distribution on the integers less than $x$? On the *positive* integers less than $x$, sure, but then the limit of the mean is the limit of $(x+1)/2$, which isn't zero.

Comment: fixed it, thanks.

Comment: But with the coprimality problem, the limit is the same however you take it. With the mean problem, you get a different answer if you take the limit over intervals $[-x,x+1]$, $x\to\infty$.

Comment: That's a good point. but are you saying that if a sequence of pairs of probabilities and events $(p_n,A_n)$ with $p_n=P_n(A_n)$ converge to $(p,A)$ in a way that $p$ does not depend on $A_n$, then $p=P(A)$ for some probability measure $P$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64498/probability-that-two-random-numbers-are-coprime-is-frac6-pi2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Define a measure of a set $\Omega$ in the plane to be the limit of number of relatively prime points in $t \Omega$ divided by $t^2,$ as $t$ goes to infinity. It can be shown that for "nice" sets this is a measure, which is a multiple of the Lebesgue measure. The multiple is precisely the limit you talk about ($6/\pi^2$). You can look for a discussion along these lines in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507573) if you want to know more.

Comment: nice paper, thanks!

Comment: @Igor Rivin : For the purposes of the first question, what reason is there for considering any set $\Omega$ other than, say, $(0,1)^2$?  If the answer is in the paper you linked, you can just say so and I'll look at it.

Comment: @StefanSmith For your specific question, that is the only set, but it is not a priori clear that that way of defining a "random pair" is any more natural than any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with the following observation:

> One integer chosen amongst $'p'$ other integers has one chance to be divisible by $p$

1. From this we infer that the probability that  an integer is divisible by $p$ is $\frac{1}{p}$.
2. Therefore the probability that two different integers are both simultaneously divisible by a prime $p$ is $\frac{1}{p^2}$
3. This means that the probability that two different integers are  not simultaneously divisible by a prime $p$ is $$1-\frac{1}{p^2}$$

   > 4. **Conclusion:** The probability that two different integers are  never simultaneously divisible by a prime (**meaning that they are co-prime**) 
   >      is then given by
   >      $$ \color{red}{\prod_{p, prime}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2} \right) =
   >    \left(\prod _{p, prime}\frac {1}{1-p^{-2}}\right)^{-1}=\frac {1}{\zeta (2)}=\frac {6}{\pi ^{2}} \approx  0,607927102 ≈ 61 \%}$$

Where should recall from the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) we have the following Euler identity

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \zeta(2)=\prod _{p, prime}\frac {1}{1-p^{-2}} $$

By similar Token, The probability that $m$ numbers are co-prime is given by

$$ \color{red}{\prod_{p, prime}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^m} \right) =
\left(\prod _{p, prime}\frac {1}{1-p^{-m}}\right)^{-1}=\frac {1}{\zeta (m)}}$$

Here $\zeta$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). $$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} $$